# Converting this string to a date

Tags: c#, datetime

I have to parse a string into a DateTime, and I've done it before but I can't be able to find the formating I used exactly and am unable to reproduce it.

Here is the string: 
`9/4/2015 12:09:06 PM`

I am pretty sure I just used DateTime.Parse before, however I can't figure out what CultureInfo and Globalization I used.

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: what is '9' and '4' - Septermber or April?

Comment: You should post some code indicating you tried.

Comment: We really, really need a canonical question on date formatting and parsing...

Comment: microsoft's documentation should help you out.

Comment: @rbm It is september

Comment: @CodeCaster - Not a SO question, but [Jon Skeet's article](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/05/05/common-mistakes-in-datetime-formatting-and-parsing/) is probably a safe bet.

Comment: @theB those are common mistakes. I can never find a decent Q&A that explain the general way to parse dates according to a given format and how to recognize or build a format.

Comment: @CodeCaster I agree, whenever I help someone on their project they tend to use other formatting for their preferred display, and finding the right parsing format is always a nuisance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `ParseExact` by specifying the format like this:

```
var datestring = "9/4/2015 12:09:06 PM";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(datestring, "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Depending if its 9th april or 4th september you can use `d/M` or `M/d`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed; specifying my own format instead of using templated ones. Where can I find documentation on this? (e.g. other symbols I can use to represent time) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165448.aspx is the only thing close I find when googling.

Comment: @anthonytimmers https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks, exactly the kind of documentation that I was looking for!